# default value in grails 2.5 domain class does not work when null is passed in

Tags: grails, default

I recently upgraded to Grails 2.5.0 from 2.3.11

I have a domain with: String country = 'USA'

An input value of null no longer defaults to USA.

Here are the results of various input values.

```
Grails      country value       country value
Version     in request          in response

2.3.11      
            not included        USA
            null                USA
            ""                  null
            "Mexico"            "Mexico"

2.5.0       
            not included        USA
            null                null
            ""                  null
            "Mexico"            "Mexico"
```

Comment: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/grails-2-3-4-rejected-value-null-td4653121.html you may find you need to add nullable true for String country as a constraint its part of lock down built in later versions of grails. Also you can try declaring default value like static mapping = { 
  country defaultValue: 'USA' } in the domain class. usually defining it at the top hard codes it- check your back end db creation too

Comment: I tried the mapping{} solution and it does not set the value to USA.

Comment: I tried the mapping{} solution and it does not set missing or null values to USA.

     country( nullable: false ) returns an error when I pass in null or ""

     {
      "code": "030",
      "message": "Property [country] of [class gvl.Premises] cannot be null (*030*)",
      "object": "gvl.Premises",
      "field": "country",
      "rejected-value": null
    }

This is not the solution we are looking for. 
It seems as though something was changed or broken in Grails 2.5

Comment: Possibly, it maybe worth testing out 2.5.1 or one step back to 2.4.5 to see if it works with either of those.